# Cannot find a proper Huffman algorithm

Tags: matlab

I am currently writing a code for Huffman encoder for 5 symbols, I have built the complete  tree (adding and sorting the symbols and storing the locations at each stage), but the problem is that I cannot get a relation between the locations of the symbols and the zeros and ones, so can any one help me in finding this relation to build the code words for each symbol?

```
A=[0.15 0.1 0.4 0.3 0.05];;
B = sort (A, 'descend');
[B,M1]=sort(B,'descend');
len= length (A);
Location = cell(1,len-2);
for n = 1:len-2
    T=B(len)+B(len-1);
    X=[len, len-1];
    B(X)=[];
    new_len=length(B);
    B(new_len+1)=T;
    [B,M]=sort(B,'descend');
    Location{n} = M ;
    len=length(B);

end
```

Comment: I don't see how you're representing your tree. Also, I suspect that you don't want to sort the input twice. When you do that you lose the index information from the original array and `M1` is always `1:n`.

Comment: Dear beaker , thank you for your support. As you can seen , i have sorted the probabilities at the beginning then i have iterated 3 times ( so that at the last stage of the tree i will have 2 symbols as required ) , at each iteration i add the last two symbols then i remove them and add this summation then i sort again . At the end i will get the locations of each stage , the problem is that i cannot  find a relation to relate this locations with 0s and 1s to form the code words  . Also  i have sorted the input twice to the get the initial locations of the sorted probabilities .

Comment: I see how you're creating `Location`, I just can't see how to reconstruct that into a tree. I might have to think about that for a bit. As for sorting the input twice, by doing that you're losing the information you're trying to get: the initial locations. If you do `[B,M1]=sort(A,'descend');` instead of sorting twice, you'll get the correct information.

Comment: Thank you beaker for your help . Ok , i will wait for any idea you offer me to reconstruct the tree  and i will notify you if i reach any thing new

Comment: @beaker , R u still there ? i have got the idea of reconstructing the tree

Comment: @Johnadams Sure, I'm back. Really, the best way is to construct the tree as you go, but go ahead and post your updates so we can have a look.